# InvalidUseOfMatchersException in Unit test Java

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a class UserService that i testing. Here it is:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDao.loadUserByLogin(login);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with login: " + login + " not found");
        }
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        for (Role role: user.getRoles()) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getLogin(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

    public User findUserByLogin(String login) {
        User user = userDao.loadUserByLogin(login);
        return user;
    }

    public User findByLoginAndPassword(String login, String password) {
        User user = findUserByLogin(login);
        if (user != null) {
            if (passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
                return user;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And I have a problem to write unit test from method `public User findByLoginAndPassword(String login, String password)`
This is my test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    private User getTestUser(){
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Role(1L, "ROLE_CLIENT")));
        return new User(1, "test login", "test name" , "test password", roles);
    }

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    // Test from method UserService.loadUserByUsername
    // if we get from userDao null then should throw UserNotFoundException, if user not null then we get userDetails
    // instance with 1 authority
    @Test
    public void loadUserByUsernameTest(){
        when(userDao.loadUserByLogin(any())).thenReturn(null);
        Assertions.assertThrows(UsernameNotFoundException.class, () -> userService.loadUserByUsername(any()));
        when(userDao.loadUserByLogin(any())).thenReturn(getTestUser());
        Assertions.assertEquals(userService.loadUserByUsername(any()).getAuthorities().size(), 1);
    }

    // Test from method UserService.findUserByLogin
    // if we request user then we get test user with same login and method userDao.loadUserByLogin invoke once
    @Test
    public void findUserByLogin(){
        when(userDao.loadUserByLogin(any())).thenReturn(getTestUser());
        Assertions.assertEquals(userDao.loadUserByLogin(any()).getLogin(), getTestUser().getLogin());
        verify(userDao).loadUserByLogin(any());
    }

    // Test from method UserService.findByLoginAndPassword
    // if we request user then we get test user with same login and methods userDao.loadUserByLogin and
    // passwordEncoder.matches invoke once    
    @Test
    public void findByLoginAndPassword(){
        when(userDao.loadUserByLogin(any())).thenReturn(getTestUser());
        when(passwordEncoder.matches(any(), any())).thenReturn(true);
//below is line 71!
        Assertions.assertEquals(userService.findByLoginAndPassword(any(), any()).getLogin(), getTestUser().getLogin()); 
        verify(userDao).loadUserByLogin(any());
        verify(passwordEncoder).matches(any(), any());
    }

}
```

I also have TestConfig.class:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public UserService userService(){
        return new UserService();
    }
    
@Bean
    public UserDao userDao(){
        return mock(UserDao.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return mock(PasswordEncoder.class);
    }

}
```

And when i start test from findByLoginAndPassword(), i have InvalidUseOfMatchersException:

```
Invalid use of argument matchers!
1 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
-> at service.UserServiceTest.findByLoginAndPassword(UserServiceTest.java:71)
-> at service.UserServiceTest.findByLoginAndPassword(UserServiceTest.java:71)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
1 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
-> at service.UserServiceTest.findByLoginAndPassword(UserServiceTest.java:71)
-> at service.UserServiceTest.findByLoginAndPassword(UserServiceTest.java:71)
```

I understand, then problem in my 2 String arguments, but i can`t resolve this.
I tried use (any(), any()) or (any(), anyString()), or (any(), eq(eny())) or any combination of these options. Please, help my and please, explain to me why this is happening??

Comment: Try using two real strings instead of using ArgumentMatchers.

Comment: Yes, it work! Thanks! But, why i cant use any(), any()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the offending line, `Assertions.assertEquals(userService.findByLoginAndPassword(any(), any()).getLogin(), getTestUser().getLogin());`, you are calling the service under test, i.e. the `userService`, passing it the result of `any()`. This is not appropriate usage of a matcher, it has to be used with a mocking call (`when(...)`) or a verification call. In this place you can use any 2 strings and, with the current test setup, they will match - e.g. `Assertions.assertEquals(userService.findByLoginAndPassword("bob", "123").getLogin(), getTestUser().getLogin());`.

Going one step further though, this test setup can be improved. You see, you may pass the user name "bob" to the method, but even if it passes "patrick" to `findUserByLogin(login)` the test will succeed, because you have configured `any()` in the line: `when(userDao.loadUserByLogin(any())).thenReturn(getTestUser())`. Consider an alternative:

```java
    @Test
    public void findByLoginAndPassword(){
        when(userDao.loadUserByLogin("test login")).thenReturn(getTestUser());
        when(passwordEncoder.matches("123", "test password")).thenReturn(true);
        Assertions.assertEquals(userService.findByLoginAndPassword("test login", "123").getLogin(), getTestUser().getLogin());
        //
        // The verifications below are redundant with the new code
        // if e.g. passwordEncoder.matches() is not called with the configured
        // arguments, Mockito will catch it and report it as an error,
        // unless you have explicitly configured it not to (lenient mocks)
        //
        // verify(userDao).loadUserByLogin("test login");
        // verify(passwordEncoder).matches("123", "test password");
    }
```